# Best way to extract information from file

Tags: python, file, extract

For example my file is:

```
Game #51236595 Tourney #123698521 Hand #9865653215
player luisgustavo call
player otherplayer fold
player otherother  check
```

I want to get the information in best way possible. 
Remember that all files are in this format. What changes are the numbers and players

EDIT: Ok but this is not a homework.
I've done this a few times but I do not think is the best way.

```
with open(".myfile", "r") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if "Game" in line:
            game_number = line[line.find('#')+1 : line.find("Tourney")-2]
            tourney_number = line[line.find('Tourney #')+9 : line.find("Hand")-2]
            hand_number = line[line.find('Hand #')+6 : ]
        elif "player" in line:
            player_name = line[line.find(' ')+1 : line.rfind(' ')]
            player_action = line[line.rfind(' ')+1 : ]
```

The code works perfectly. But I do not think it's a good code must have a better way to do this.

Comment: This seems as a homework, please show us what you have tried and we'll gladly help you if you have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
with open('.myfile', 'r') as myfile:
    header = myfile.readline().split()
    game_number, tourney_number, hand_number = header[1], header[3], header[5]
    for line in myfile:
        player_name, player_action = line.split()[1:]
```

This uses `split()`<sup>[[docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)]</sup> and is much more pythonic.

Comment: I was going to write something similar to this. But instead of calling line.split() twice on the last line, just do it once, e.g.: `player_tag, player_name, player_action` = line.split().

Comment: It's also not entirely clear but from the example in the question it may be possible for there to be multiple games in a single file. In that case, the "game" line detection needs to be checked for and handled in the loop.

Comment: @ChrisPhillips Good call on the last line, when I wrote it I wasn't thinking clearly :).  If there is more than one game per file, you would have to associate player data with a given game, and I'm assuming that since the "working code" doesn't do this, mine doesn't need to either.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the code was much better now. I can already pick up several games per file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csv.reader` with a custom dialect for a general solution with a lot of the details already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer given by @brc above:

```
with open(".myfile", "r") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        parts = line.split()

        if parts[0] == 'Game':
            game_tag, game_number, tourney_tag, tourney_number, hand_tag, hand_number = parts
            continue

        player_tag, player_name, player_action = parts
```

This clearly extracts the pieces you need with a minimum of overhead. Of course, you'll also need to actually do something with the values. Also, I'm assuming there can be multiple "game" lines in a file. If that's not true, you can just check for it in the first line.